# Comparing against an undefined property is not an error in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, casting, comparison-operators

In JavaScript, comparisons that involve undefined properties are evaluated as `false`, rather than throwing an error, even in "strict" mode.
This has created more than one hard-to-resolve bug in my code.

**Is there any way to a) detect these mistakes, or b) mitigate against them?**

```
> let x = {foo: 1}
> x.foo == 2 // Sensible behaviour
false
> x.floo // Where floo is a typo.
ReferenceError: floo is not defined
> x.floo == 2 // Nonsensical behaviour
false
```

Comment: Is that nonsensical behaviour? 2 is indeed not equal to undefined. But one answer is: TypeScript.

Comment: This is a feature of JS: you can dynamically add attributes to objects. and it is very common to code 'if x.floo {...}' where the if block only executes when x.floo is not undefined. JS is a loosely-typed language by design. It is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: JavaScript is a web language and there is a bunch of bugs on web pages - do you want every 4th(?) page to not work and show an error ? Also browsers are not much compatible, so it is made in a way to work smoothly with lot of small bugs to have most pages working...

Comment: Thanks. I understand why JavaScript works the way it does, but since I can't be the only person with typos in their code I hoped there might be some insights into dealing with this. Ideally one that didn't involve me learning TypeScript!

Comment: *"Is there any way to a) detect these mistakes"* static typing, like Typescript or Flow *", or b) mitigate against them?"* a modern IDE. VS Code for example. But in my experience, even Notepad++ has enough autocomplete abilities that I rarely get that kind of typos anymore.

Comment: Typescript lesson 1: converting your JS code to Typescript with one simple command: `ren *.js *.ts` done, your javascript files have been transpiled to Typescript ;)

Comment: Alas, I'm using emacs with gulp, so my autocomplete options aren't what they could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although @jonrsharpe is absolutely right that you should use Typescript if you need that level of control, just for fun, here's a pure javascript implementation. Wrap your object in `strict(...)` and you will get reference errors on undefined props:

```js
const SPECIAL_PROPS = [
    // well-known symbols
    ...Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Symbol).map(p => Symbol[p]),
    // used by JSON.strinfigy
    'toJSON',
    // something else?
];

let strict = obj => new Proxy(obj, {
    get(t, p) {
        if (p in t)
            return t[p];
        if (!SPECIAL_PROPS.includes(p))
            throw new ReferenceError(`property ${String(p)} is not defined`);
    }
});

let x = strict({foo: 1})
x.foo == 2 // Sensible behaviour
x.floo == 2 // Reference error
```

Needless to say, this is a purely runtime check, which kinda defeats the whole purpose.

Comment: for reaching faster than me +1

Comment: On the contrary, I can use this during development to catch exactly these typos. I wasn't aware of Proxy objects, thank you!

Comment: @Eoin Bad idea. This will create bugs in otherwise valid code. Are you aware of methods like `toString` or `toJSON` or `valueOf` or all the new Symbols? someting like `JSON.stringify(x)` will throw! or `"" + x` or just `+x` and several more

Comment: Your timing is perfect. I've just used `JSON.stringify`, and realised this, so I've commented out the Proxies again. I did catch two additional typos using them though, so it has been worthwhile I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

```js
let x = {foo: 1}

let handler = {
  get: function(target,prop,reciver){
      if(!target.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
        throw new Error('Sorry property do not exist')
      } else{
        return target[prop]
      }
  }
}

let proxy = new Proxy(x,handler)

console.log(proxy.foo)
console.log(proxy.floo)
```

Comment: hmm, looks familiar ;)

Comment: @georg Yeah but there was no answer when i started typing, and also there's one difference this uses  `target.hasOwnProperty(prop)` which is better option to check existence of key as it doesn't go down scope chain, where as `in` will go down scope chain if not found on current chain,

Comment: @georg yes it's like saying i need `static type of dynamic language`,

Answer (score 0):

You can check `item === undefined`.

Or define additional property `.isNull()` in Object prototype that covers this case:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'isNull', {
    value: function (obj) {
        return (obj === null || obj === undefined);
    }
});
```

Usage:

```
if(Object.isNull(x)) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Great, this works in a program where I didn't know if the property was defined yet. My problem arises when there is a property that should always be defined, but I mistype it's name, e.g. `foo` and `floo` in the question.